# Passing Parameters To report using url address

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters

I'm developing some reports for Main Page in Dynamics Ax, however the problem i've got is connected with SSRS. Typical scenario i have report A and report B, i need to open report A when clicking on report B. Opening report itself is correct, but passing parameters is more tricky. After some research i got to the point when I want to run report A in browser using the adress

> http://(server address)/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/Dynamics/Reports.VendorsOpenTransactionsCount.AutoDesign1&rs:Command=Render&VendOpenTrans_dataAreaID=dor&VendOpenTrans_p1=2011-07-21&VendOpenTrans_p2=2011-07-21

and then i get  report  displayed(main window) but non of the parameters are validated into proper textboxes, and changing the value of them doesn't have any impact.
can anyone here help me with that "challenge"

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I  believe the critical difference is whether you are passing parameters (via URL) to a report that is using database engine or the SSAS - the analytical engine as a data source.

If your data source is the analytical engine then your parameter should be given in the 'dimension format', rather than in the precise format, like &parmname=140, etc. Allow me to explain using specific example and using SSAS data source for this illustration (there is plenty of solutions available on the net for the database engine based solution, including Microsoft postings).

My server name is FRELASM.
So, I have SSAS data source called DealerSource (not visible here).

I have parameter defined in the parameter's section of the SSRS as: `@DwDimDealerCorpDlrNbr`

In SSAS I have the following dimension:

- `[Dw dim Dealer]` that has attribute: `[Corp Dlr Nbr]` ==> giving: `[Dw dim Dealer].[Corp Dlr nbr]`

What I want is to show a report for a single dealer 'number' (but it is a text field, hence the leading zeros) equal to 00140. So, I am looking for Corporate dealer number=00140.

The parameter passing DOES NOT WORK if I use [this](http://frelasm:8080/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Rpt8168_01/rpt8168_SSAS_TEST&rs%3aCommand=Render&DwDimDealerCorpDlrNbr=00140) [this would be find against database engine, but it does not work with SSAS).

What you need is this:

1. replace constant `00140` with `[dimension].[attribute].[value]`
2. do not use `&` character, rather replace it with: `%26`.

So, the working version is [this](http://frelasm:8080/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Rpt8168_01/rpt8168_SSAS_TEST&rs%3aCommand=Render&DwDimDealerCorpDlrNbr=%5BDw%20Dim%20Dealer%5D.%5BCorp%20Dlr%20Nbr%5D.&%5B00140%5D).

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

It explains about when you can pass parameters via URL. Maybe your parameters are not set to Prompt for user input. HTH.

Comment: Cam L, thank you for your effort, but i've already went through msdn and checked this and it didn't worked out for me, more over on some forum i found a hint that sometimes removing "rs:Command = Render " helps but it also didn't help